# how to apply webpack.config.js file it on react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I know this question not quiet right. I couldn't figure how ask this question. When I created a react app using `npx create-react-app my-app` and started the react app I seen some additional logs in my terminal which is for `webpack v5.66`. You can see this image. I want to remove those logs and only want to see the warnings and errors that comes from my app.

[image]

### webpack.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: 'warn',
  },
};
```

By defaults its 'info' in webpack v5.66

I don't know to much about webpack can anyone tell how to apply this in react app so the logs can be removed. If there any other instruction need to added please suggest me. Help me.